# Concatenar horizontalmente valores de Array multidimensional

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, ascii, array-bidimensional

Mi problema es que no soy capaz de concatenar los valores como lo deseo.

**A continuación doy contexto**:

Pasa que estoy haciendo una librería que me devuelve ciertos valores, en este caso es texto en tipografía figlet (solo es importante saber que básicamente contiene cadenas de texto) y la librería hasta ahora solo es capaz de devolver un conjunto de "letras únicas" en un array bidimensional en el siguiente formato:

```
[
  [
    "",
    "  _     ",
    " | |__  ",
    " | '_ \\ ",
    " | | | |",
    " |_| |_|",
    "        "
  ],
  [
    "", 
    "       ",
    "   ___ ", 
    "  / _ \\",
    " |  __/", 
    "  \\___|",
    "       "
  ],
  [
    "", 
    "  _ ",
    " | |", 
    " | |",
    " | |", 
    " |_|",
    "    "
  ],
  [
    "", 
    "  _ ",
    " | |", 
    " | |",
    " | |", 
    " |_|",
    "    "
  ],
  [
    "",
    "        ",
    "   ___  ",
    "  / _ \\ ",
    " | (_) |",
    "  \\___/ ",
    "        "
  ]
]
```

Todo esto es generado por mi librería, en incluso se puede generar en una sola cadena de texto o de manera individual por letra, pero me parece que el camino va por la via de los arrays así que así lo hice, pero ahi están otras formas por si alguien le interesa.

El punto del problema es que he intentado de todo, loops in loops, reduce, map y hasta filter y nada me funciona, tal vez la cabeza ya no me da jaja.

La meta es lograr concatenar cada item (linea horizontal) correspondiente a la de la matriz adyacente de manera que se pueda hacer concatenación de la tipografía, es decir algo como:

```
[
   ["  _     ","      ","    _ ","  _ ","        "],
   [" | |__  ","  ___ ","   | |"," | |","   ___  "],
   [" | '_ \\", "/ _ \\", " | |"," | |","  / _ \\ "],
   [" | | | |","|  __/",  " | |"," | |"," | (_) |"],
   [" |_| |_|"," \\___|", " |_|"," |_|","  \\___/ "]
]
```

Ye después de esto es mas fácil (o eso quiero pensar) un ejemplo podría ser:

```js
let biArray = [
   ["  _     ","      ","  _ ","  _ ","        "],
   [" | |__  ","  ___ "," | |"," | |","   ___  "],
   [" | '_ \\", " / _ \\", "| |"," | |","    / _ \\ "],
   [" | | | |","|  __/",  " | |"," | |"," | (_) |"],
   [" |_| |_|"," \\___|", " |_|"," |_|","  \\___/ "]
]

let result = ""

biArray.forEach(chain => {
  chain.forEach(string => {
    result += string;
  })
  result += "\n"
})

console.log(result)
```

En el ejemplo parace que no sale tan bien, pero es porque es ascii, una vez que se modifica por una entrada de texto se estropea, pero en consola se ve muy bien desde la genreación de la fuente.

Si alguien puede ayudarle estaría verdaderamente agradecido. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice algunas pruebas y creo que eso te funcionará:

```
// Definimos el array que queremos convertir
let arrOriginal = [
    [
        "",
        "  _     ",
        " | |__  ",
        " | '_ \\ ",
        " | | | |",
        " |_| |_|",
        "        "
    ],
    [
        "", 
        "       ",
        "   ___ ", 
        "  / _ \\",
        " |  __/", 
        "  \\___|",
        "       "
    ],
    [
        "", 
        "  _ ",
        " | |", 
        " | |",
        " | |", 
        " |_|",
        "    "
    ],
    [
        "", 
        "  _ ",
        " | |", 
        " | |",
        " | |", 
        " |_|",
        "    "
    ],
    [
        "",
        "        ",
        "   ___  ",
        "  / _ \\ ",
        " | (_) |",
        "  \\___/ ",
        "        "
    ]
];

// Primero calculamos la letra que tenga más filas. En teoría todas deberían tener la misma cantidad de filas, pero es mejor hacerlo de esta manera para evitar un error de javascript
let maxFilas = 0;
arrOriginal.forEach(arrLetra => {
    // Si la letra actual tiene más filas que la anterior, sobreescribe el valor de maxFilas
    if (arrLetra.length > maxFilas) maxFilas = arrLetra.length;
});

// Definimos nuestro array bidimensional de salida
let biArray = [];

// Hacemos el par de bucles anidados
for(let i = 0; i < maxFilas; i++) {
    // Definimos primer nivel
    biArray[i] = [];
    for(let j = 0; j < arrOriginal.length; j++) {
        // Definimos segundo nivel (si la fila de la letra actual no existe, se define como un string vacío "").
        biArray[i][j] = typeof arrOriginal[j][i] != "undefined" ? arrOriginal[j][i] : "";
    }
}

console.log(biArray);
```

Comment: Me parece que es correcto ajajaja no estaba teniendo en cuenta para nada el maximo de las filas, excelente!!! Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Acá se almacena el array.
const arg = [];
for(let x = 0; x < 7; x++){
    const line = [];
    for(let y = 0; y < source.length; y++){
        line.push(source[y][x]);
    }
    // Aquí se agrega la línea
    arg.push(line.join(' '));
}
```

Lo hice suponiendo que todos los caracteres miden 7 como largo.

El resultado final es:[image]

Tenga en cuenta que las uní con .join(' ');
Podrías mantenerlo como un array, si lo necesitas.

Comment: Excelente, por respeto a la respuesta que me ayudo primeramente no pongo esta como la respuesta aceptada pero cabe destacar que es excelente, muchas gracias!